# C++11 std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++11, stdvector

I'd like to use `std::array` from C++11 as a field of my own class. It takes two template parameters (first defines type of data, second defines size of an array).

But I know the second parameter only in constructor. I'm not familiar with C++11 standard, but I suppose that it's impossible to set a template parameter during execution.

Are there any alternatives for `std::array`? `std::vector` is probably a little too much, cause I will never change the size of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::vector` is the simplest thing to use; although as you say, it does waste a few bytes if you'll never need to resize it.

`std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, initialised using the result of `new T[size]`, would be the most efficient thing; it should be the same size as a pointer, and will delete the allocated memory for you when it's destroyed. It's not copyable, though; you'll need to provide a copy constructor for your class if you want it to be copyable. It's also less convenient than `std::array` and `std::vector`, since it doesn't have the interface of a standard container. You could perhaps write a STL-style wrapper for it if you need that; but I'd just use `std::vector`  in that case.

Comment: I would say use a std::vector over a unique_ptr<T[]>, the former is compatible with all the standard library functions that work on iterators.  In fact the whole point of std::array is to provide such an interface over a normal array.

Comment: @user1131467: Indeed, `std::vector` is much more convenient; but the OP did express a concern about efficiency, so perhaps saving a few bytes is important.

Comment: If you are going to write a STL-style wrapper, then at least it would also have to know its size. You can only not bother about capacity.

Answer (score 11):

> I'm not familiar with C++11 standard, but I suppose that it's impossible to set a template parameter during execution.

You can't pass a value only known at run-time as a template argument ... the code created by a template instantiation has to be created at compile-time, therefore it can't depend on a run-time value.

Some possible solutions are to create template specializations for some common array-size values, and then a possible max-size value.  I think though that would be a pretty inefficient way to work.

To be honest, in your situation, a `std::vector` would most likely be the best solution since you can simply call `resize()` on the vector to make it the correct size at run-time through dynamic allocation.

Comment: or, instead of `resize()`, use the `std::vector (size_t n)` constructor.

Comment: @phresnel: or `reserve` + a sequence of `push_back`/`emplace_back` if not all your items should be the same.

Answer (score 6):

std::array is for when you know the size statically at compile-time.  If you don't know until runtime, use a std::vector.  If you don't resize it there is not much overhead.

```
class Container
{
    vector<T> v;
    Container(int i) : v(i) { v.shrink_to_fit(); }
};
```

If you are worried about space:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Not sure if there is a way to construct the vector already trimed.  It doesn't seem to be required by the standard to be constructed trimed, although in practice many implementations will do this.

BTW You can also construct a vector with vector(size_t N, T t) which will set every initial element to t (without this the elements are default constructed).

Comment: IIRC, the vector is constructed with *exactly* the capacity you ask it for. No need to shrink afterwards. The copy-and-swap trick to shrink a vector also relies on that.

Comment: Interestingly, for some benchmarks, there is no overhead at all and `std::vector`-code yields the same, vectorized SSE code as with native arrays (with g++ at least)

Comment: I think an array is allocated in place and a vector is allocated dynamically.

Comment: @user1131467: In principle: Yes. In practice: The optimizer might put away dynamic allocations, depending on circumstances.

Comment: @phresnel: I mean that sizeof(Container) above will be constant, whereas if I had used an array, sizeof(Container) would be proportional to array size.  I am not sure the optimizer can do anything about that, because it doesn't know at compile time whether or not it will be resized from some other compilation unit it hasn't been linked with yet.

Comment: @user1131467: Across compilation units it is of course harder, unless you have very decent LTO. And, usually, apart from NRVO/RVO, optimizers may  not change observable behaviour of the program as a whole. But often, I am in the situation, where containers are stored privately, ideally through the pimpl idiom. The compiler will then treat the vector-code in isolation of other units and might apply such optimizations then.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the size of the array until run-time, then you want to use a std::vector.